# Display a very large text into a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle, yui

I need to load a very large text into a dialog box using YUI or jQuery and I'd like to know the best way to do it. I have an Oracle CLOB column which I need to show if the user needs to know what was stored there. Since CLOB data are huge, it is impossible to load everything. Any ideas?

Comment: You could display the first 1000 characters, and give a link to the full data on its own page if the user needs it.

Comment: How huge is "huge"?  If it's so big as to make it literally impossible to show in a browser window, then your fundamental problem is usability anyway, and @Oliver's suggestion or something like it would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was thinking about something dynamic, somehow to get chunks of data each "n" scroll down, or something like that. This is an "specification" in which I disagree but I don't have the power to stop using CLOB fields this way.

Comment: Have you already considered using Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple divs and load each one with what's left of your clob content when your user drops cursor in it : you can do this either using [connection manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) for YUI 2 or nodeList if you are using YUI3 (here's an [example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/nodelist.html) of how to use it)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a fixed-size DIV and add: `overflow-y:auto`.